# Does glut have something to set the mouse position to the middle of the screen?

Tags: glut

I'm adapting an opengl tutorial that uses the win32 api to glut. I found this win32 function:

```
SetCursorPos(middleX, middleY);
```

Does glut allow me to set the cursor like this?

Comment: It's usually *very* bad manners to move the users mouse pointer around like that. The OpenLook desktop did that a lot back in the '90s and **boy** was it annoying! (Or at least I think it was OpenLook; I remember it as being based on Sun's NeWS but for X11. Looked great for its time, but sucked to use, and the frequent pointer warping was one of the worst features.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `glutWarpPointer()` in [Nate's GLUT implementation](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html), though I can't find that entry point in the official [spec](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html).